# Error de doctrine: Access denied for user en Symfony-4

Tags: doctrine2, symfony

Estoy siguiendo el tutorial https://symfony.es/noticias/2017/05/02/symfony-4-un-ejemplo-practico/, para empezar con Flex y son Symfony.

El caso es que al ejecutar: `./bin/console doctrine:database:create`
me devuelve:
```
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 ```

El caso es que no se donde tengo que indicar los valores de conexión a la bbdd.

¿Alguien me puede aclara donde se configura los valores de conexión de la bbdd?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Symfony4 y en entorno de desarrollo se recomienda indicar la conexión en el archivo .env:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#content_wrapper